# Is it possible to get all events I'm invited to using Facebook's Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-events

Currently, Facebook's Graph API for Events (https://graph.facebook.com/me/events) does not return all events I'm invited to. It only returns those that I've said maybe, attending, or no to.

Am I missing something? Is there anyway around this? (perhaps using FQL or some other clever way)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `event_member` table with `user_events` permission

`SELECT eid,rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid=me()`